# How to pass a parameter to the url and go to another page without using Router Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Please tell me, from one component, I need to pass the parameter and go to another page, for example loacachost: 8080 / home? {Id}, and on the other component, which is initialized when switching to loacachost: 8080 / home, get this parameter

Comment: Your answer is in reading the documentation :) https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5 And if that doesn't help you, show us what you have tried and where you have failed.

Comment: But why don't you want to use router ca you elaborate on the use case?

Comment: @AJT_82 I can not use RouterLink

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal I do not use SinglePage, everything is built on portlets

Comment: then in that case use the window object that is the obvious goto , see the simple answer below to get some idea

Comment: I'm maybe getting confused here. Could you present your actual use case here.

Answer (score 0):

So angular is just another framework on vanilla javascript , with your use case what you need is the window object to redirect appending the query string from one component and then on the new url load which is basically second component read this query param like

```
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let name = params.get("name");
```

mind you search param works on all latest browsers, to redirect use

```
window.location='yoururl'+'name';
```